# Watch youtube moview on a Mac using QuickTime

Tags: macos, safari, quicktime, adobe-flash

Is it possible to watch youtube videos on a Mac using QuickTime as it is on iOS? 
How to force Safari to render youtube video stream in QT plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’re a couple of Safari extensions that will do this. ClickToPlugin and ClickToFlash.

http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/

Both versions will swap out the Youtube Player for a standard HTML5 player. The extension also allows you to download the Youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can since youtube videos are flash based (or in some cases HTML5 player based).

I did find a link that might help you a little:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2015789?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

I use [Videobox](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24405/videobox)

I often have to use Videobox's mini browser. I copy the URL from the YT site to the mini browser.

I set the Videobox output to a QT format. you can even batch downloads. I hope this helps.

Comment: good work around, but it is quite complicated - copying URL ald watching video in other app.

Comment: it's not so bad, and I can make a queue to download and convert. But I hope you find something that works for you.